# Open Chrome and Close Activity (But let Chrome Open)

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have a simple APP then opens up chrome on a page. However, if the user presses  'back' button, chrome closes and my blank activity comes up. I wish i could open chrome and close the blank activity.

Here's my code, as simple as that.

```
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

If i call this.finish() after opening the chrome activity, the chrome closes as well.

Would apreciate any help. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

just call the `finish();` method after your intent.